# This should be deleted but its edited instead

Tags: button

I've been working on this project for hours!!

I need to create a simple calculator in JAVA and cannot figure out how to implement the arithmetic into the coding. Everything else works fine...including the buttons.

However, I have no idea HOW or even WHERE to include the arithmetic in the code without the compiler crashing.

Any help pleasee!!

Answer (score 1):

> However, I have no idea HOW or even WHERE to include the arithmetic in
>   the code without the compiler crashing.

*There may be many answers.*

Think on following point

When to perform operation? after User clicks on Equal sign but what if user wants to add(or somthing else) than you need to write code for that also.

So think in this way.

---

You can use `ScriptEngineManager` to calculate expressions you are creating in `String`.

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

engine.eval(expression);//evaluate expression String
```

---

But Please use `try{}catch{}` to handle exception.

Answer (score 1):

Very simplified answer, but it'll give you an idea of how to proceed:

Declare two new fields:

```
...
private JTextField inText;

private int firstOperand, secondOperand;
```

Add some logic, handling click on "+" button and "=" button.

```
...
    else if (actionCommand.equals("Clear"))
        inText.setText("");
    else if (actionCommand.equals("+")) {
        firstOperand = Integer.parseInt(inText.getText());
        inText.setText("");
    } else if (actionCommand.equals("=")) {
        secondOperand = Integer.parseInt(inText.getText());
        inText.setText(Integer.toString(firstOperand + secondOperand));
    }
```

Comment: ok I'm new to JAVA as a side note, now the addition works but when I try to add subtraction. division, and multiplication then NONE of the buttons work. Is this due to an order/precedence error?

Comment: No, it's because you should implement the logic of * / and - by yourself. This code handles only +

Comment: @Marco I know the logic, I just don't know how to implement it...If i knew how to code the logic then I wouldn't need help right? Lol thanks though

Comment: But he gave to you the code, try to read it not just paste it and you will understand the logic no? After all, you should only replace "+" with "-" (* etc.)

Comment: Right and I did, the only problem I have is with the equals button, I know i have to store my answer in a variable and then get that variable and use an operand to store the answer in a final variable, however the equals only ADD when I use his logic. I edited my code above so you can see what i'm talking about

Comment: I'm just having trouble with the equals logic while including the four operands.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on TAsk's answer, this can be done with very little code:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
...

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

        if (actionCommand.equals("Clear"))
            inText.setText("");
        else if (actionCommand.equals("Reset"))
            inText.setText("");
        else if (actionCommand.equals("="))
            calculate();
        else
            inText.setText(inText.getText() + actionCommand);
    }

    public void calculate()
    {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        try
        {
            inText.setText(engine.eval(inText.getText()) + "");//evaluate expression String
        } catch (ScriptException ex)
        {
            inText.setText("");
        }
    }
```

If the button pressed is any other than clear/reset/= just append the button text to the textfield. No need to have seperate actions for buttons 0-9,+,-,*,/ since you want to do the same on any of them.

When user presses "=" use the ScriptEngine to calculate, then display the result.

If you want a simpler calculate, it can be done something like this:

```
String e = inText.getText();
if(e.indexOf("+") >= 0)
{
    String[] n = e.split("+");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(n[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(n[2]);
    inText.setText(String.valueOf(a + b));
}
else if(e.indexOf("-") >= 0)
{
    String[] n = e.split("-");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(n[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(n[2]);
    inText.setText(String.valueOf(a - b));
}
else if...
```

Just add some bounds checking and error handling.

Comment: Thank you but there's an error when "ScriptEngineManager' is coded...do I need a special import to implement this in Eclipse?

Comment: Added imports to answer, but press "Ctrl+Shift+O" and Eclipse should import them for you.

Comment: Thanks it works! But just to know, is there another way to do this without implement 'ScriptEngineManager' in the caculate method? Like could I use a switch or some kind of if statement or will this be inefficient?

Comment: Not necessarily inefficient, but it'll require more work/original thoguht, on the other hand though, you'll probably learn more from it.

Comment: Nice Answer Martin.. :)